# access denied while accessing a file in windows shared location

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking, shared

So there two computers (A and B) connected for file shareing. A needs to access a folder from B.
In comp A, in windows explorer below path is working
\B\sharedFolder\file.txt
Successful able to open the file.
But in my .net application .net framework 4.7.2
Same path is not working. Getting access denied.

Please let me know how to access this file.

Tried using network credentials. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To access UNC file shares in a application you have to provide credentials for allowing the application access over the share.

Something like this:

```
string filePath = @"\\server\share\file.txt";
string username = "username";
string password = "password";

try
{
    using (NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password))
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("File contents: {0}", fileContents);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading file: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

If you are using an older version of .NET it might not support the using statement for non-disposable objects. You should use this instead:

```
try
{
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("File contents: {0}", fileContents);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading file: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: It seems NetworkCredentials is not implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable  to used in using statement

Comment: Its not working still access is denied. Without using statement

Comment: What credentials are you using?

Comment: Credentials of the remote computer.  Username: domain\username             password: password

Comment: Are the two computers in an AD? just since you're using domain. It should be working with the above code :)

Comment: What version of  .NET supports the using statement for non-disposable objects?  I'm using VS2022 with .net 7.0 and I get the "NetworkCredential: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'" error,